# Cancel Push Notification with OneSignal in Unity3d SDK

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, sdk, onesignal

I am using Unity3d OneSignal SDK for sending a push notification.
I have to setup Local Push notification using the onesignal SDK, can it possible?

As well, I also want to Cancel all previous set notifications.
I am trying this method : OneSignal.ClearOneSignalNotifications(); 
But it can't works.